# Add custom dropdown list (datatables plugin) in correct layout

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

How can I add a `dropdownlist` next to the search field in the `datatables` plugin?

Adding one outside where the plugin is initialized and positioning it inside is too dirty. It should be possible to add a custom dropdownlist right? It doesn't have to be dynamic, just a dropdownlist with some values.

Like this: [image]

How can I do this ?

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
      $('#myTable').DataTable({
        "language": {
            "sProcessing": "Bezig...",
            "sLengthMenu": "_MENU_ resultaten weergeven",
            "sZeroRecords": "Geen resultaten gevonden",
            "sInfo": "_START_ tot _END_ van _TOTAL_ resultaten",
            "sInfoEmpty": "Geen resultaten om weer te geven",
            "sInfoFiltered": " (gefilterd uit _MAX_ resultaten)",
            "sInfoPostFix": "",
            "sSearch": "Werknemers zoeken :",
            "searchPlaceholder": "Naam/BSN/Personeelsnr",
            "sEmptyTable": "Geen resultaten aanwezig in de tabel",
            "sInfoThousands": ".",
            "sLoadingRecords": "Een moment geduld aub - bezig met laden...",
            "oPaginate": {
                "sFirst": "Eerste",
                "sLast": "Laatste",
                "sNext": "Volgende",
                "sPrevious": "Vorige"
            }
        }
    });
      $(document).ready(function() {

        var table = $('#example').DataTable({
          "columnDefs": [
          { "visible": false, "targets": 2 }
          ],


          "order": [[ 2, 'asc' ]],
          "displayLength": 25,
          "drawCallback": function ( settings ) {
            var api = this.api();
            var rows = api.rows( {page:'current'} ).nodes();
            var last=null;

            api.column(2, {page:'current'} ).data().each( function ( group, i ) {
              if ( last !== group ) {
                $(rows).eq( i ).before(
                  '<tr class="group"><td colspan="5">'+group+'</td></tr>'
                  );

                last = group;
              }

            } );
          }
        } );

    // Order by the grouping
    $('#example tbody').on( 'click', 'tr.group', function () {
      var currentOrder = table.order()[0];
      if ( currentOrder[0] === 2 && currentOrder[1] === 'asc' ) {
        table.order( [ 2, 'desc' ] ).draw();
      }
      else {
        table.order( [ 2, 'asc' ] ).draw();
      }
    });
  });
    });
    $('#example23').DataTable( {
        dom: 'Bfrtip',
        buttons: [
            'copy', 'csv', 'excel', 'pdf', 'print'
        ]
    });
</script>
```

Comment: More help full tutorial: [How to Add Custom Dropdown in DataTable](https://devnote.in/how-to-add-custom-dropdown-in-datatable)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Well we can add the custom buttons to `DataTable` but they come on left side of the table(pretty much far from search box).

I don't know if there is any option available for adding the fields near the search box, But when I got the similar requirement I added(actually appended it to `DataTable` search box div) it manually with help of bootstrap classes like below

**Demo :**  https://jsfiddle.net/Prakash_Thete/uo110be1/4/

Add below code after the `DataTable` initialization.

```
 $('<div class="pull-right">' +
        '<select class="form-control">'+
        '<option value="volvo">Volvo</option>'+
        '<option value="saab">Saab</option>'+
        '<option value="opel">Opel</option>'+
        '</select>' + 
        '</div>').appendTo("#example_wrapper .dataTables_filter"); //example is our table id

 $(".dataTables_filter label").addClass("pull-right");
```

Comment: Thanks, I tried adding your code but I don't see any dropdownlist being added above my table. The id is correct so that's not it. Where exactly do I put your code? I added my entire script tag containing the datatablesplugin in my original question.

Comment: Please add my code after initialization of table on which you want `drop-down`.

Well i don't see your code for adding the `drop-down` list. Can you please create an JSFiddle of your code so that I will have a look at the actual problem ?

Comment: (edit: updated link, still had some old code in it) Yea I added the code here: https://jsfiddle.net/w756ozgc/2/

Comment: I have modified my `JSFiddle` according to your code. Please have a look at it(Removed the unnecessary code you have added).

Comment: One quick queston: is it possible to have the dropdownlist right from the search box instead of left? I know I asked for left, but right looks better I think.

Comment: Yes absolutely just replace class `pull-right` with `pull-left`.

Comment: Lets assume we add an id `customField` to the appended div. How could we pull off data by `$("#customField").val()` before the ajax call to add it to the `ajax.data` property? The underlying question is about DT-lifecycle hooks. I want to add a dropdown after rendering and use an user-selected option in the ajax call.

Comment: For clarification of my previous comment: The id `#customField` must of course be added to the `select`-element.

Answer (score 5):

You can use the datatables [collection](https://datatables.net/reference/button/collection).

```js
$('#myTable').DataTable( {
    buttons: [
        {
            extend: 'collection',
            text: 'Flag',
            buttons: [
                { text: 'High priority',   action: function () {  } },
                { text: 'Medium priority', action: function () {  } },
                { text: 'Low priority',    action: function () {  } }
            ],
            fade: true
        }
    ]
} );
```

Please note - this property requires the Buttons extension for DataTables.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/1.5.1/js/dataTables.buttons.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Another option is to use the DOM property of the table initializer.
e.g.

```
    "dom": "<'row'<'col-sm-4'f><'col-sm-2 customDropDown'><'col-sm-2'r><'col-sm-4'l>>" +
        "<'row'<'col-sm-12't>>" +
        "<'row'<'col-sm-6'i><'col-sm-6'p>>",
```

See https://datatables.net/reference/option/dom for the meaning of the different letters (flrti...)

You can add a custom class (customDropDown) and then use it to append the dropdownbox.

```
$('<div>' +
    '<select class="form-control">' +
    '<option value="Processing">Processing</option>' +
    '<option value="Error">Error</option>' +
    '<option value="Completed">Completed</option>' +
    '</select>' +
    '</div>').appendTo("#DocumentsTable_wrapper .customDropDown");
```